# How to compare xml-element with variable in jsp

Tags: xml, jsp, jstl

im trying to compare a xml-element with a variable which i get from a post request.
Therefor my first .jsp uses

```
<form action="test.jsp" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="test" ><input type="submit">
```

In the test.jsp i try the comparison with

```
<c:import var="xml" url="http://localhost:8080/myxml.xml" />
<x:parse xml="${xml}" var="output"/>
<x:forEach var="adress" select="$output/order/adress">
        <x:if select="city = param.test">
            <li>Test</li>
        </x:if>
</x:forEach>
```

but its always false.
When i use a string instead of `param.test` everything works fine.

How can i use my input for the comparison?

Comment: can you try  ${param.test} and see if it helps

Comment: unfortunately this brings an error: According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute select does not accept any expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end i could solve my problem with the following code:

```
<x:forEach select="$output/order/adress" var="item">
    <x:set var="city" select="string($item/city)"/>
    <c:if test="${city == param.test)}">
        <li>works</li>
    </c:if> 
</x:forEach>
```